# PHP: Log errors to a logfile locally

Tags: php, apache, logfile

I am trying to setup PHP to log errors locally so that I can solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964554/unexpected-connection-reset-a-php-or-an-apache-issue).

However, I can't even get this to work. I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html), but nothing. Does it only log fatal errors or what?

Is there anything else I need to make sure of?

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question - you can edit the earlier version ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964641/php-log-errors-to-a-logile-locally )

Comment: I wasn't re-asking, that was accidental. I am only aware of it now.

Comment: I have voted to delete the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need these settings:

log_errors = on

error_reporting = E_ALL

if you want to set these in .htaccess, you can do somn like:

php_value log_errors 1

php_value error_reporting 6143

Comment: Ok, the htacess has worked for me. I will just have to use this! Thanks. :)