# Connection Reset on MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, connection-reset

OK, I'm flummoxed. 
I'm trying to execute a query on a database (locally) and I keep getting a connection reset error. I've been using the method below in a generic DAO class to build a query string and pass to Zend_Db API.

```
public function insert($params) {
    $loop = false;
    $keys = $values = '';
    foreach($params as $k => $v){
        if($loop == true){
            $keys   .= ',';
            $values .= ',';
        }
        $keys   .= $this->db->quoteIdentifier($k);
        $values .= $this->db->quote($v);
        $loop = true;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " ($keys) VALUES ($values)";

    //formatResult returns an array of info regarding the status and any result sets of the query
    //I've commented that method call out anyway, so I don't think it's that
    try {
        $this->db->query($sql);
        return $this->formatResult(array(
                true,
                'New record inserted into: '.$this->table_name
        ));
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $this->formatResult($e);
    }
}
```

So far, this has worked fine - the errors have been occurring since we generated new tables to record user input. The insert string looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(`id`,`title`,`summary`,`description`,`keywords`,`type_id`,`categories`) VALUES ('5539','Sample Title','Sample content','
\'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et pellentesque mauris. Curabitur hendrerit, leo id ultrices pellentesque, est purus mattis ligula, vitae imperdiet neque ligula bibendum sapien. Curabitur aliquet nisi et odio pharetra tincidunt. Phasellus sed iaculis nisl. Fusce commodo mauris et purus vehicula dictum. Nulla feugiat molestie accumsan. Donec fermentum libero in risus tempus elementum aliquam et magna. Fusce vitae sem metus. Aenean commodo pharetra risus, nec pellentesque augue ullamcorper nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam vel elit libero. Vestibulum in turpis nunc.\'','this,is,a,sample,array',1,'category title')
```

Here are the parameters it's getting before assembling the query (var_dump):

```
array
    'id' => string '1' (length=4)
    'title' => string 'Sample Title' (length=12)
    'summary' => string 'Sample content' (length=14)
    'description' => string '<p>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et pellentesque mauris. Curabitur hendrerit, leo id ultrices pellentesque, est purus mattis ligula, vitae imperdiet neque ligula bibendum sapien. Curabitur aliquet nisi et odio pharetra tincidunt. Phasellus sed iaculis nisl. Fusce commodo mauris et purus vehicula dictum. Nulla feugiat molestie accumsan. Donec fermentum libero in risus tempus elementum aliquam et magna. Fusce vitae sem metus. Aenean commodo pharetra risus, nec pellentesque augue'... (length=677)
    'keywords' => string 'this,is,a,sample,array' (length=22)
    'type_id' => int 1
    'categories' => string 'category title' (length=43)
```

The next port of call was checking the limits on the table, since it seems to insert if the length of "description" is around the 300 mark (it varies between 310 - 330). The field limit is set to VARCHAR(1500) and the validation on this field won't allow anything past bigger than 1200 with HTML, 800 without.

The real kicker is that if I take this sql string and execute it via the command line, it works fine - so I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

I've tried extending the server parameters i.e.
[Unexpected Connection Reset: A PHP or an Apache issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964554/unexpected-connection-reset-a-php-or-an-apache-issue)

So, in a nutshell, I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for anyone else experiencing this problem - the issue is to do with Zend_Db_Statement - or rather the preg library that this component relies on. It's been flagged in the Zend issue tracker: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8399, but its not strictly a problem with the Zend lib. You may or may not experience this problem depending on your server environment. In my case, this error occurred on:

Win XP,
Wamp 2
PHP 5.3

It can be resolved by using

```
db->getConnection()->exec($sql)
```

which effectively executes the sql directly via the adapter (PDO etc). Alternatively, you can modify your server to rectify segfaulting in PCRE itself (though I confess I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about this). Hope that helps anyone else with the same issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me! :) Btw, that should be `$db->getConnection()->exec($sql)`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are googling and find this post about connection reset when doing MySQL query:

Apart from the answer from sunwukung, please also check that if there is a bottle-neck in your MySQL setting, especially this one:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1M
```

You can change it to a larger number.  Here is mine:

```
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

Now it works.

**Explanation:**

As you can read from the setting name, connection reset is mainly the result of too large data-set going in and out of MySQL, which "Terminate" the connection to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post exact error message ($this->db->errorInfo() if you use PDO) ?
Are you sure that you have db connection established?

Comment: the connection is resetting, so I don't have any script output

Comment: and what if you set PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT to false ?

Comment: nope, still dies. If I create a fresh PDO instance, it's fine, it's whenever it hits the Zend_API that it breaks.

Comment: I've just located an identical bug on the Zend Framework issue tracker - with bare PDO/MySQL calls, it's fine - so it's something in Zend.